# JSX typing with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, jsx

I'd like to use the type checking  features of JSX in VueJS. It seems that babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx can only offer to implement a render function with JSX XML syntax. What about type checking ? Is it possible ?